# jqGrid: Is it possible to submit a search query as a json message?

Tags: rest, jqgrid

jqGrid communicates with the server using query parameters (GET) and form parameters (PUT / POST). Is it possible to submit a json message instead? For example, instead of submitting myQuery?rows=10&page=1&country=spain, can we submit this HTTP payload to the server: {"rows":"10", "page":"1", "country": "spain"?
THis functionality would be needed if we want to interact with a RESTful web service that expects a pre-defined message structure. On the other hand, GET requests don't have a body, so I'm wondering if passing a json message to a GET RESTful service is even possible? I am designing both sides of the service (jqGrid + CXF). My concern is about exposing a clear contract for my service, as opposed to just accepting an undescribed Map of parameters. I will appreciate feedback on how this could be achieved with jqGrid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serializeGridData` callback to convert the posted parameters to one JSON string. For example

```js
serializeGridData: function (postData) {
    return JSON.stringify(postData);
}
```

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7365228/315935) describes more options which you could need for communication with RESTful service.

If we speak about RESTful services, then it's important to mention that parameters like `rows`, `page`, `sidx` and `sord` are **not a subject of classical RESTful URL** because the parts are **not a resource**. So the usage of *parameters* of URL ("?param1=value1&param2=value2&...") would be absolutely complaint to RESTful service. OData uses (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg312156.aspx) for example) the information about paging also as parameters. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15979809/315935) provide an example of accessing RESTful Open Data Protocol (OData) services of Windows Azure Mobile Services.